# Using pass keyword in a while loop to skip over values

Tags: python, while-loop

Can anyone help me to spot where I am going wrong here please??
I need to print the following values on order to the console: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13.
However my code below is printing the whole list from 0 to 13?
Thanks in advance!

```
x = 0

while x < 14:
    if x > 4 and x < 11:
        pass
    
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

Comment: I believe you mean to use `continue`, not `pass`. `pass` does nothing; it's a placeholder. The logic is still a bit off, but it makes more sense.

Comment: interesting! if I swap continue for pass it throws an error! Coding challenge I am doing says to use pass... weird!

Comment: They may have used `pass` to mean "fill in this part yourself". And you shouldn't get an error from that replacement.

Comment: I'm with you - I thought it had to be continue as it makes more sense, however still throwing an error when swapping to continue!! odd... thanks for your help, much appreciated

Comment: @Carcigenicate Infinite loop most likely. They aren't incrementing the x variable in the condition

Comment: Ah, so a TLE "error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pass` keyword is just a placeholder for code. Your coding challenge is probably not telling you to use it, but instead using it as a placeholder for the code. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) on the pass statement.

Instead, `continue` could be used. Continuing is another statement used only in loops. It will cause the loop to skip to the next iteration without completing the rest of the code. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) on the continue statement.

Also, you need to increment the `x` variable no matter what. If you don't increment it in the if condition, it will cause an infinite looping error. Remember, it must be before the continue statement, else it won't run.

```py
x = 0

while x < 14:
    if x > 4 and x < 11:
        x += 1
        continue
    
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

Comment: instructions were a bit diffused to put it in some way! thank you so much !

Comment: @Jose What do you mean "instructions were a bit diffused"?

Comment: the instructions of the coding challenge I'm doing I meant, sorry!

Comment: your input could not be more logical, you were spot on!

Answer (score 0):

Please use continue instead of pass keyword.
Also you need to increase the value by 1 of variable x during write continue statement.

Comment: if I swap continue for pass it throws an error! Coding challenge I am doing says to use pass... weird!

Comment: You need to change logic as as described otherwise it’ll run infinite times.

Answer (score 0):

Start with your basic "while as a for" loop.
Note that it's better to include the values you will use as the loop parameters:  use `x <= 13` in place of `x < 14`:

```
x = 0
while x <= 13:
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

Now, exclude the items you do *not* want to print.
Use a simple "if" with only the `print` inside:

```
x = 0
while x <= 13:
    if x <= 4 or x >= 11:
        print(x)
    x += 1
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
11
12
13
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted, pass is a null statement; it's not going to do anything. One way to use it might be to make it one side of an `if`-`else` structure:

```py
x = 0
while x < 14:
    if x > 4 and x < 11:
        pass
    else:
        print(x)
    x += 1
```

On the other hand, if you want to use `continue` there, it fits far more naturally inside a `for` loop.

```py
for x in range(14):
    if x > 4 and x < 11:
        continue
    print(x)
```

since the structure takes care of the iteration.

Comment: To confound your enemies, `print(*(x for x in range(14) if x<=4 or x>=11),sep='\n')`